# how far can the epoch time go back in time?

Tags: jodatime, epoch

I was trying out http://www.epochconverter.com/ and I can do year 100, but when I go to year 99, it seems to break down and report 1999 instead of 0099.  Is this a bug?  How far back is epoch time supposed to be able to represent.

I also tried plugging in MIN_LONG+1 to joda-time which reported -292275055-05-16T16:47:04.192Z so basically year -292275055 which sounds a bit more correct than 1999 and epochconverter.com can't even parse the min long.

What is the minimum value of epoch time allowed?  Can I use min long?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory, there is no limit. "Epoch time" is simply the number of seconds before/after a defined point in time (Jan 1 1970, midnight GMT); with a sufficiently wide numeric type, you can describe any time in these terms.

In practice, such a time value becomes meaningless beyond certain limits:

- A signed 32-bit integer has a minimum value of about -2 billion, corresponding to a date in late 1901.
- If you are using a floating-point type for dates, it will lose resolution beyond some point. Do not use single-precision (32-bit) floats for time values; they have a resolution of about two minutes (128 seconds) for the current date! 64-bit floats are fine for the foreseeable future, though, as they can exactly represent all 32-bit integers.
- Time zones were not standardized before 1900 or so, so trying to represent a time before then is an inexact affair.
- The Gregorian calendar was not defined before 1582 (and was not used universally until as late as the 1920s!), so trying to use standard date conversion routines on dates that far back will give incorrect results.
- Similarly, the Anno Domini ("AD") calendar was not defined until 525 AD. Additionally, note that there is no year 0.
- Some libraries may have other arbitrary limits or restrictions. For instance, the one you're running into here is that the Javascript date library assumes that years less than 100 are shorthand for years between 1900 and 1999.

Answer (score 3):

By "epoch time", I'm guessing you mean what Wikipedia calls "[Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)", the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. With a 32-bit signed integer, it can represent dates from 1901-12-13 through 2038-01-19 (GMT) (as you can find by entering the values of -2^31 and 2^31-1 in the epochconverter web site you linked). There is no minimum or maximum date or precision to Unix time itself, the only limit is what sort of numbers you use to define it.

[Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) apparently has instants in time defined as milliseconds since the epoch, using a `long` (64-bit signed integer) to store it. This has a range of years from -292275055 (or 292,275,055 BC if you prefer) to +292278994 (292,278,994 AD).

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth, after a bit of trial-n-error, it appears `gnu`'s `Unix/Linux` utility `date` has epoch-seconds are inclusively bounded at :

```
 67,768,036,191,694,799 
-67,768,040,609,723,038
```

This might look rather arbitrary without context, but once mapped, they're :

```
Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 EST  2147485547
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 LMT -2147481748
```

Both of those years are sorta close to `2^31` but off by just a tiny bit, which turns out to be :

```
 2147485547 = 1900 - 1 + 2^31
-2147481748 = 1900 - 1 * 2^31
```

Answer (score -1):

January 1, 1970 on Unix like systems.

Comment: Nope. You can go in negatives.

Answer (score -1):

January 1, 1970. If you go before the Epoch time in 64-bit systems, then you will get an underflow which will create a time 5x greater than the expected time of the universe. This is what caused the error 53 for iPhone 5S+

Answer (score -1):

The reason it interprets your input year 99 as the year 1999 is because more likely than not it uses the Javascript function Date.parse() to parse your date, which has this particular anomaly.

You can get the correctly parsed timestamp at another online timestamp parser such as http://www.convertunixdate.com/ - you might need to enter your year as a 4 digit number to make sure it isn't changed.